# Долго запускается в отладке android приложение на эмуляторе и на реальном устройстве

Tags: java, android

Приложение весит всего 10мб, а когда нажимаю запустить его то задержка примерно секунды полторы и только потом оно запускается. Другие приложения, которые весят в десятки раз больше открываются моментально. Как этот момент промониторить и разобраться из-за чего это и где копать? (Android Studio)

Comment: Вы проверяете отладочную версию приложения или релизную? Отладочная версия действительно запускается долго.

Comment: Release версия в build.gradle стоит, может еще где-то нужно изменить?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, на эмуляторе у вас всегда будет собираться именно debug версия, если хотите посмотреть точно релизную версию, создайте ключ, подпишите апк и установите его на телефон.

Comment: @Binary Build variants debug меняете на release и собираете релиз.